# Swift JavaScriptCore not working with large files?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, xcode, javascriptcore

https://github.com/gg2001/monero/blob/master/monero/NewWallet.js

I have a js file that is quite large 6000 lines and JavaScript core does not seem to be able to retrieve variable values whereas running the same file in any web browser works fine for me. When I try to retrieve the value of a variable it shows up as undefined, but when I use a js console in a browswer it shows up fine. I am speculating that this is due to the size of the file because when I put

```js
var helloWorld = "Hello World";
```

in the front of the js file this swift code can retrieve it

```js
func helloWorld() {
        if let variableHelloWorld = self.jsContext.objectForKeyedSubscript("helloWorld") {
            print(variableHelloWorld.toString())
        }
    }
```

but when I put it at the end it cannot.

Answer (score 1):

Normally this indicates a parsing error. Try adding an error handler to `self.jsContext` before calling `objectForKeyedSubscript()` and see if it outputs anything insightful.

```
self.jsContext.exceptionHandler = { context, exception in
    print("JS Error: \(exception?.description ?? "unknown error")")
}
```

Although your JS code may be valid in a browser console, iOS Safari doesn't support as many Javascript features as newer browsers.

I did see a line in your JS source code beginning with just a semicolon (followed immediately by `(function`). I wonder if the parser might complain about an empty line without a statement..? Maybe nothing, though.

Comment: Found a solution around this by implementing a WKWebView and avoiding JavaScriptCore so I never got around to trying this out. Hopefully this solves someone elses problem.